# How to add a node at the beginning of a single linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am new to the programming world.
I have written code for adding data in beginning using single linked list and my code  is not working as I expected.I am not getting any warning or error.

I am unable to print data which was taken from user please help me to fix it .

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct st
{
    int roll;
    char name[20];
    struct st *next;
};

void begin(struct st**);
void display(struct st*);

main()
{
    struct st *headptr=0;
    begin(&headptr);
    begin(&headptr);
    begin(&headptr);
    display(headptr);
}

void begin(struct st **ptr)
{
    struct st *temp;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct st ));
    printf("enter ur roll\n");
    scanf("%d",&(temp->roll));
    printf("enter ur name\n");
    scanf("%s",(temp->name));
    temp->next=*ptr;
    temp=*ptr;
}

void display(struct st *ptr)
{
    while(ptr)  
    {

        printf("%s\t %d\n",ptr->name,ptr->roll); //Here its not printing as I expected                                                       
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: sry I couldn't get u?what i mean is that i am unable to print the data which was inserted.

Comment: @Anitasingh: Just don't say "everything is fine", "it's working perfectly", "my program works" when you come here to ask a question. Everything is *never* fine, and there's no need to pretend otherwise. Just get to the point of what you expect, what is happening instead and what you've done so far by way of analysing the  problem. That's all we ask for.

Comment: @sestus hey i joined stackoverflow today itself and u both answer is correct so i accept both answer

Comment: @sestus sry really i dint knew only one is accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The begin function does not set headptr to point to something. Either you made it by mistake, or you need some reading in list manipulation.

You need to change

```
temp->next=*ptr;
temp=*ptr;
```

to

```
*ptr = temp;
```

at start. Then you can set your next nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to fix these things urself,make research before posting here

```
   *ptr=temp; instead u did
    temp=*ptr//What does this means its make no sense please study the basic things before trying for linked list.
```